# Finding a file path, then using that file path to copy+paste the file

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt

So, I'm trying to make a command prompt that will:

1.Find the path of another command prompt

2.Copy and paste that file

So far I have the first part down. I can locate said command prompt using `cd\` then `DIR /S C:\Foldername name.cmd`the problem I'm running into is: I would like the command prompt to be able to find it wherever the folder is, so that if I move the folder the command prompt can still be used to copy the file to the specified location, however, I can't figure out how to copy+paste the file, without typing in it's location myself.

Is there some way for me to have the command prompt find the path of the file, then input the path it found into the copy command so that it knows what it's copying? Or am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be using `DIR` to locate it? Or is there another command I overlooked that will magically solve this problem?

Thank you in advance to anyone who responds.

Comment: what do you mean by `Find the path of another command prompt`? Each console has a CWD but you can't access it from outside. And `DIR /S /A C:\Foldername name.cmd` just finds a file named `name.cmd` inside C:\Foldername. The `/A` part is useless because you must provide attributes with it like `/A:HS`... See `dir /?` for more information

Comment: By, find the path of another command prompt, I mean for the command prompt to not just locate it, but to somehow use the path, for example if it were to find `name.cmd` at `C:\users\wesley\desktop\foldername` then it would be able to copy it from there. I hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. How is `name.cmd` related to "another command prompt"? There's only a single command prompt in Windows: cmd.exe and *.cmd is just a script that cmd.exe can run. It's not a command prompt. Looks like you want to copy the *.cmd file to somewhere, right? But from another *.cmd file or right from inside the *.cmd file itself?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm sorry for not explaining it properly.